# Kentico CSS List Menu styling

Tags: css, kentico

[image]I am to implement this structure with kentico

```
       <li class="megamenu_button"><a href="#_">Mega Menu</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li class="aa"><a href="#_" class="megamenu_drop">About Us</a><!-- Begin Item -->
            <div class="dropdown_4columns dropdown_container"><!-- Begin Item Container -->
                <div class="col_12">
                    <img class="img_left" src="images/about_us_img.png" width="125" height="146">
                    <ul class="list_unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#_">FreelanceSwitch</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#_">Creattica</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#_">WorkAwesome</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#_">Mac Apps</a></li>
                  </ul> 
                </div>
            </div><!-- End Item Container -->
        </li><!-- End Item -->
</ul><!-- End Mega Menu -->
```

The design is meant to have at least 6 menu headers with sub-menu each.
The challenge is I don't even know how to approach the design. I am currently using aspx master template. All suggestion is welcome.
Attached to this is an image of the expected production. I have the that suit the listing above.

Comment: copy their code, read it, try to understand it. You can't expect us to write all the code for you. If you can't do it on your own, get some tutorials on HTML and CSS to gain better understanding of the technology

Comment: @Lukas, that's rather hash! If you have a solution steps, speak if not, you need not insult! All I need are steps to guide. If I don't understand css and html, how then will I be here?

Comment: It wasn't meant to be harsh. I never stated you don't understand html and css, I only suggested steps to take if you don't. The fact, that noone answered your question yet does mean something. The way SO works is that you should ask question only after you try it yourself and either don't understand what failed in your approach or if there is better approach. SO is not meant to give you instructions to create something, tutorials are meant to do that. I didn't try to be hars nor insult you, I tried to explain the way SO works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make use of nested repeaters (CMSBasic Repeaters).
May you find below useful links on how to do it.

[Option 1](http://devnet.kentico.com/Knowledge-Base/Design-and-css/Creating-a-Mega-Menu-%28step-by-step%29.aspx) 
[Option 2](http://devnet.kentico.com/Knowledge-Base/Design-and-css/Creating-a-Mega-Menu-using-Hierarchical-transforma.aspx)